# The image upload could not load the picture

Tags: reactjs, node.js

```
const [profile, setProfile] = useState(null)

    console.log(profile)

    const handleFileInputChange = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.files[0])
        setProfile(e.target.files[0])
    }

<div className="mt-2 flex items-center">
                                <span className='inline-block h-8 w-8 rounded-full overflow-hidden'>
                                    {profile ? (
                                        <img src={profile} alt='Profile pic' 
                                        className='h-full w-full object-cover rounded-full' />
                                    ) : (
                                        <RxAvatar className='h-8 w-8' />
                                    )}
                                </span>
                                <label htmlFor='file-input'
                                className='ml-5 flex items-center justify-center px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300
                                rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white hover:bg-gray-50 cursor-pointer'>
                                    <span>Upload File</span>
                                    <input type='file' name='profile' id='file-input' accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png"
                                    onChange={handleFileInputChange} className='sr-only' />
                                </label>
                            </div>
```

I am trying to upload the photo by clicking the input button and the photo could not be shown. May I ask what is the problem the photo could not be loaded properly?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you use `URL.createObjectURL` to generate the URL of your uploaded file?

```html
<img src={URL.createObjectUrl(profile)} alt='Profile pic' className='h-full w-full object-cover rounded-full' />
```

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-dom-createobjecturl-method/